# Simple LSTM in PyTorch with Sequential module

Tags: deep-learning, torch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

In PyTorch, we can define architectures in multiple ways. Here, I'd like to create a simple LSTM network using the `Sequential` module.

In Lua's torch I would usually go with:

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.SplitTable(1,2))
model:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.LSTM(inputSize, hiddenSize)))
model:add(nn.SelectTable(-1)) -- last step of output sequence
model:add(nn.Linear(hiddenSize, classes_n))
```

However, in PyTorch, I don't find the equivalent of `SelectTable` to get the last output.

```
nn.Sequential(
  nn.LSTM(inputSize, hiddenSize, 1, batch_first=True),
  # what to put here to retrieve last output of LSTM ?,
  nn.Linear(hiddenSize, classe_n))
```

Answer (score 9):

Define a class to extract the last cell output:

```py
# LSTM() returns tuple of (tensor, (recurrent state))
class extract_tensor(nn.Module):
    def forward(self,x):
        # Output shape (batch, features, hidden)
        tensor, _ = x
        # Reshape shape (batch, hidden)
        return tensor[:, -1, :]

nn.Sequential(
    nn.LSTM(inputSize, hiddenSize, 1, batch_first=True),
    extract_tensor(),
    nn.Linear(hiddenSize, classe_n)
)
```

Comment: Hi, How do I proced from here? something like:

net = nn.Sequential( ... )

for epoch in epochs:
    outputs = net(inputs)

I tried the above and still got errors

Comment: what error you get , can you show me .. the above is toy example  you defin the model and give values for the variables (inputSize , hiddenSize, classe_n ) base on your work

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LSTM cell documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#lstm) the *outputs* parameter has a shape of (seq_len, batch, hidden_size * num_directions) so you can easily take the last element of the sequence in this way:

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(10, 20, 2)
input = Variable(torch.randn(5, 3, 10)) 
h0 = Variable(torch.randn(2, 3, 20))
c0 = Variable(torch.randn(2, 3, 20))
output, hn = rnn(input, (h0, c0))
print(output[-1]) # last element
```

Tensor manipulation and Neural networks design in PyTorch is incredibly easier than in Torch so you rarely have to use containers. In fact, as stated in the tutorial [PyTorch for former Torch users](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nn_tutorial.html) PyTorch is built around Autograd so you don't need anymore to worry about containers. However, if you want to use your old Lua Torch code you can have a look to the [Legacy package](http://pytorch.org/docs/legacy.html).

Comment: I've coded an LSTM in this exact way beforehand. But my question is how would you do it within the Sequential module `nn.Sequential`? The LSTM returns two values, `output` and `hn` in your code, how to retrieve output[-1] in the `Sequential` fashion?

Comment: I don't think that it's fair to downvote my answer however I have updated it inserting more evidences of the fact that using containers as in Lua Torch is out-dated.

Comment: According to [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/accessing-intermediate-data-in-nn-sequential/637), they wanted to get rid of the `Sequential` module in PyTorch but they kept it for its convenience as a container. I guess that it's not possible to access intermediate output within a `Sequential` container.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned there's nothing like a `SplitTable` or a `SelectTable` in PyTorch. That said, you are allowed to concatenate an arbitrary number of modules or blocks within a single architecture, and you can use this property to retrieve the output of a certain layer. Let's make it more clear with a simple example.

Suppose I want to build a simple two-layer MLP and retrieve the output of each layer. I can build a custom `class` inheriting from `nn.Module`:

```
class MyMLP(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels_1, out_channels_2):
        # first of all, calling base class constructor
        super().__init__()
        # now I can build my modular network
        self.block1 = nn.Linear(in_channels, out_channels_1)
        self.block2 = nn.Linear(out_channels_1, out_channels_2)

    # you MUST implement a forward(input) method whenever inheriting from nn.Module
    def forward(x):
        # first_out will now be your output of the first block
        first_out = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(first_out)
        # by returning both x and first_out, you can now access the first layer's output
        return x, first_out
```

In your main file you can now declare the custom architecture and use it:

```
from myFile import MyMLP
import numpy as np

in_ch = out_ch_1 = out_ch_2 = 64
# some fake input instance
x = np.random.rand(in_ch)

my_mlp = MyMLP(in_ch, out_ch_1, out_ch_2)
# get your outputs
final_out, first_layer_out = my_mlp(x)
```

Moreover, you could concatenate two MyMLP in a more complex model definition and retrieve the output of each one in a similar way.
I hope this is enough to clarify, but in case you have more questions, please feel free to ask, since I may have omitted something.